# is it possible to trigger database change and fire an event in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, events, replication

I have a master replication environment, that the master database is using MSSQL and the replication is using MYSQL, and they are both synced with each other. A Laravel application is using the replication. Now what I need is to have a trigger on Mysql (replication) when a record gets updated and it should be sent to Laravel to fire an event.(As stupid as it may sound) I know I can write a procedure for storin the updated record in a table and make the changes later but then I have to check the table on a schedule and it's gonna waste resources. Is it even possible? or are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel provides two solutions:

- [queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues) : it is a daemon (a service) that will listen for any job(some special commands) you specify, and execute them asynchronously. It supports in memory and in database drivers. So you can see what fits your resource usage.
- Also, Laravel provides the possiblity to [schedule tasks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling), you can use it to poll for the newly stored records. It should not be hard to implement if your records use Eloquent timestamps.

Or you can combine both, theoretically, you can use a scheduled task to manually pop and execute the Laravel queue jobs.